# Wordpress core color picker (iris) in widget - refresh when edited in wordpress customizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, colors

I have added the Wordpress Core color picker (iris) to a widget I developed, but when you edit the color, there is no change triggered. As a result, the `iframe` (live preview) for the customizer does not update unless you trigger a change in another input field.

Javascript to iniitalize the color picker

```
var myOptions = {
// you can declare a default color here,
// or in the data-default-color attribute on the input
defaultColor: '#000',
// a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
change: function(event, ui){

},
// a callback to fire when the input is emptied or an invalid color
clear: function() {},
// hide the color picker controls on load
hide: true,
// show a group of common colors beneath the square
// or, supply an array of colors to customize further
palettes: true
};

// Add Color Picker to all inputs that have 'color-field' class
$('.color-field').wpColorPicker(myOptions);
```

Note:

I tested adding the code below to the change call back.

```
change: function(event, ui){
    $(this).trigger('change'); 
},
```

This will trigger a change and update the `iframe` when the user clicks the color picker, but it happens before the color value is saved.

Does anyone happen to know how to access the event after the color chosen has been saved?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you enqueue color picker styles and scripts? `wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');` and `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');`?

Comment: I tested that just now, and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I found a workaround. Thanks for the response though ding_d!

Comment: Feel free to post the workaround as an answer, so that it can help someone who might have the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it's a solution that seems to solve the issue.

```
 add_action( 'admin_footer-widgets.php', array( $this, 'print_scripts' ), 9999 );

public function print_scripts() {
    ?>
    <script>
        ( function( $ ){

            function initColorPicker( widget ) {
                widget.find( '.color-field' ).wpColorPicker( {
                    change: _.throttle( function() { // For Customizer
                        $(this).trigger( 'change' );
                    }, 3000 )
                });
            }

            function onFormUpdate( event, widget ) {
                initColorPicker( widget );
            }

            $( document ).on( 'widget-added widget-updated', onFormUpdate );

            $( document ).ready( function() {
                $( '#widgets-right .widget:has(.color-field)' ).each( function () {
                    initColorPicker( $( this ) );
                } );
            } );



        }( jQuery ) );

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

I believe the workaround here is that you want to activate the ('.color-field').wpColorPicker() -> .on('widget-added widget-updated')  as well as when the document is ready.